# The placement of Next button in app for warehouse men

Tags: usability, mobile, buttons, placement

The app will be used on an Android device with touchscreen but physical keyboard. The device allows for bar code scanning so there's also a handle for more comfortable usage. There are a few steps that warehouse men have to perform in order to complete an activity of registering items delivered to stock. For each step they can either type information and click "Next", or they can scan the information and be moved to the next page automatically. The client wants to have the summary of all steps visible on the screen constantly and there you can click on each of the info and edit if needed. The idea is as below:

[image: Steps with problematic Next (arrow) button placement]

So the question is, how to place the Next button in this case? We use Next only if we input information manually, otherwise it is done automatically. In the first screen it seemed logic that Next would be placed just next to a text field but then it is not consistent with other type of pages (2). If I place the next button at the bottom, it looks a bit odd on the pages like the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an vertical flow. This allows for an easier way to view the summary and have the scan button can float on the bottom part of the screen. [image]

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, the next button is CTA of the page when user fill the inputs manually. so I prefer putting it in a same place for every page. It's easier to remember for users.
The right one is much better if there is no touch keyboard overlays the page.

Comment: I think you're right that it should be in the same place and that's what I am struggling with. The flow is step by step interaction, the client wanted to have a single task per page. The summary at the bottom would grow from the bottom in the process (ex. after scanning the warehouse, on the next page we would see information about warehouse only, at the bottom). I was considering a long CTA button at the bottom of every page (under summary) but then it doesn't look like it refers to the text field at all. What do you think?

Comment: I think it's a good solution. try it! Design a unique CTA button to get the attention on page scanning.